# Ruby Gem to generate custom Text over Image Banner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a slider which shows some custom made images on the main site.
At the moment every time I want to change something I need to deploy a new image with the changed text.

I was wondering if there is a gem which can be settled up to put some custom text over a default image if several conditions are met.

Comment: Why don't you handle text overlay with client-side javascript?  Hard to imagine how this couldn't be better than re-generating images at the server.

Answer (score 1):

To do any kind of programatic image manipulation I would look at imagemagick. Think of photoshop in an open source binary. As imagemagick has been written in C you will not be able to call it directly. Instead use rmagick. Rmagick provides a nice ruby interface around imagemagick's c based API. There might be an updated way to do this as I have not worked with images in ruby for years however it's the best place to start. GL.